# Make the text "figure x" inside paragraph to be bold

Tags: html, css, figure, css-counter

I would like to apply bold formatting to **figure 1, figure2,** ...until **figure 111.**

I can only change the HTML and CSS and need to do this without using JavaScript or jQuery. Is there any way besides adding `<strong>` in HTML?

There is `::first letter` in CSS, but no `::first word`. Can I use ~like `%figure` in CSS?

```
<p>Figure 3 All incidences of ...</p>
<div id="imgcontainer" style="height: auto;">
  <p><img src="Images/misc/newsletters/msIssue7_monoAnti4_850x550.png"     style="margin-bottom: 10px;" /></p>
  <p>Figure 4 ...</p>
</div>
<div id="imgcontainer" style="height: auto;">
  <p><img src="Images/misc/newsletters/msIssue7_monoAnti5_350x370.png" style="float: left; width: 450px; margin: 8px 20px 8px 0px;" /></p>
  <p>Figure 5 Sequence information obtained from MS/MS analysis of capillary electrophoresis ...</p>
</div>
   <p><img src="Images/misc/newsletters/msIssue7_monoAnti6_850x350.png" style="width: 850px; height: 200px; margin: 8px 8px 8px 0px;" /></p>
   <p>Figure 6 Separation of ...</p>
```

Comment: If you want the texts "Figure x" to have more impact than the surrounding text, or you want, for instance when you run the site through a speech synthesiser, them to be pronounced louder, then you would use `<strong>`. Otherwise, using`< span>`s and styling them would be better.

Comment: Given that you can change the HTML + CSS and are seemingly averse to adding extra tags and styling them, you can make use of something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/atnzawen/) to auto generate the text and also style it. If you would like to use this approach, I would add an answer and also explain.

Comment: @Harry Oh, that's a good one. I would upvote that.

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks mate. I have added an answer because it is likely to be helpful for other users also :)

Answer (score 5):

Given that you have the ability to change the markup and CSS of your page and that you don't want to add extra elements (like `<strong>` etc), you could try to make use of CSS counters. Counters have very [good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=counters).

Using Counters, you can auto number the figures, add the text "Figure X" before the content and also style it without doing any additional changes to your markup. The big advantage of this is that you don't have to manually number them and don't even have to worry about any future changes to the order. CSS would automatically take care of it. You can also add any extra styling that you need.

Below is a sample snippet:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figure; /* Initializes the counter to 0 */
}
p {
  counter-increment: figure; /* Increment the counter everytime p tag is encountered in DOM */
}
p:before {
  content: "Figure " counter(figure)" "; /* Set Figure + Counter value as content */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p> <!-- Counter = 1, Before Content = Figure 1 -->
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p> <!-- Counter = 2, Before Content = Figure 2 -->
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p> <!-- Counter = 3, Before Content = Figure 3 -->
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p> <!-- Counter = 4, Before Content = Figure 4 -->
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p> <!-- Counter = 5, Before Content = Figure 5 -->
```

If you don't want to number all `<p>` tags and want to number only specific `<p>` tags then you can give them an unique class like in the below snippet. (**Note:** Even though you add an extra class, the bold text is restricted to just the "Figure X" text and doesn't apply to the entire content of that `<p>`).

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figure;
}
p.count {
  counter-increment: figure;
}
p.count:before {
  content: "Figure " counter(figure)" ";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class='count'>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<p class='count'>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<p class='count'>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
```

---

If like the snippet provided in your question, the "Figure x" text is applicable only for the second paragraph within the `div class='imgcontainer'`, you can still do this without adding any extra class like in the following snippet:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figure;
}
.imgcontainer > p + p {
  counter-increment: figure;
}
.imgcontainer > p + p:before {
  content: "Figure " counter(figure);
  padding-right: 1ch; /* More padding-right means more space between Figure x and text */
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='imgcontainer'>
  <p>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
  </p>
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>
<div class='imgcontainer'>
  <p>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
  </p>
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>
<div class='imgcontainer'>
  <p>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
  </p>
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>
<div class='imgcontainer'>
  <p>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
  </p>
  <p>Some Description</p>
</div>
```

<sup>**Note:** `1ch` means width of the "0" character in the element's font. The `ch` unit has lower browser support and I have used it only for example. You can use `px` or `em` or any such unit instead of `ch`.</sup>

Comment: Nice. And if you don't want to use a contiguous range of numbering, you can throw in a class for the new starting number. E.G. if you wanted to continue with number 100 halfway, you would write `<p class="count from100">` and `.from100 {counter-reset:figure 99}`.

Answer (score 2):

you can put desired property in a class and then add the elements to that class.

Also you are using id="imgcontainer". 
id's are unique in css (should be at least) when you want to give same properties to more than one element use classes instead of id's

Try putting all the figures in a div with class abc.
Now put these bold property in the that class.

here is the property for bold you need to add in your div.

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Answer (score 2):

though you want to change the figure1 and so on to be bold using css, as you know css only deals with **decoration**, while javascript deals with **user action**, now this can only be achived by javascript to first find out the figure word, and then adding css class to it, css has no build in **Attribute** to find out automaticaly and change the decoration of html inner element

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use JavaScript at all.